# Small delay when playing a sound for the first time with SpriteKit

Tags: audio, sprite-kit

When I play a sound using [self playSoundFileNamed], there is a small delay the first time a sound is played where the whole app freezes for about half of a second, but after that it's fine. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 18):

In my game setup method, I do something like this and it seems to work well.

Have an iVar

```
 SKAction *_ballsHitSound;
```

Set it up when load the scene

```
_ballsHitSound = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"ballsCollide.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
```

then the sound is ready to go

```
[self runAction:_ballsHitSound];
```

Comment: The pause is the initial loading of the sound. Essentially, doing all the loading of these audio files in the setup for the game is like preloading and definitely the right way to go. That pause will exist during the setup, but pause is manageable during setup.

Comment: You'll likely experience the same pause with loading a font for a SKLabel. So best to also load SKLabels with fonts you use during gameplay during setup as well. For example if you have a specific font for score popups that only get used during gameplay.

Answer (score 0):

The playSoundFileNamed: action is made to play small sounds, like sound effects of your game, not background music or such bigger sound files. If you plan to play bigger sound files you better use AVAudioPlayer class, that gives you more control over the sound reproduction.
Here's a code snippet of how to use it:

```
// Load and start background music
    NSError *error;
    NSURL * backgroundMusicURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"background-music" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:backgroundMusicURL error:&error];
    self.backgroundMusicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.backgroundMusicPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't have to play your sounds on the main thread so I would try to play it on the background thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        // Play it here
    });
```