# sprite kit frame rate dip at start and only once

Tags: sprite-kit

I have a sprite that runs and jumps (like Mario), I am using a state machine to help with running the animation actions, I am using a texture atlas, and everything works fine.

```
 - (void)jumpingphysics {

if (_JumpBool && self.onGround) {
    _doubleJumpBool = YES;
    _JumpBool = NO;

    [self catJump];
    self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 600);
}
// double jump
if (_JumpBool && _doubleJumpBool) {
    self.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0.0, 600);
    [self catDoubleJump];
    _doubleJumpBool = NO;
    _JumpBool = NO;

}
}
```

this is the method thats called.

```
 - (void)catJump {
if (_actionState == kActionStateIdle || _actionState == kActionStateWalk || _actionState ==         kActionStateJump) {
    [self removeAllActions];
    [self runAction:_jumpAction];
    SKAction *jumpFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"jump.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
    [self runAction:jumpFx];
    _actionState = kActionStateJump;

}
}
```

this is where I created the frames array animation.

```
 - (void)catJumpAnimation {
int i;

NSMutableArray *jumpFrames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:9];
for (i = 1 ; i < 9; ++i) {
    NSString *frames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"jump%d.png",i];
    SKTexture *temp = [catAtlas textureNamed:frames];
    [jumpFrames addObject:temp];

    self.jumpAction = [SKAction animateWithTextures:jumpFrames timePerFrame:1.0 / 16.0       resize:YES restore:NO];
}
}
```

The problem is when running on an iPad mini, when I jump the first time, my frame rate dips to 40, only that first time, and only on my iPad mini, not my iPhone 5 c.

I know its the [self catJump] call that causes the frame rate dip, but I'm confused why only that call causes a dip, I have other animations which do more work yet don't cause a dip.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: @LearnCocos2D loops sorry here it is.  I have a tempoary fix for this, I call the catJump method as soon as the cat sprite is initialized, so by the time the scene is ready, there won't be any frame rate dip. I don't like it tho lol :p Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: It's possibly that it's your sound file loading the first time your cat jumps. Pre-load the sound file in your setup, and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19739596/small-delay-when-playing-a-sound-for-the-first-time-with-spritekit

Comment: @prototypical YES! thats what was causing the dip! thank YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my ActionSprite.h class which handles the the methods that controls the animations and sounds.

```
 @interface ActionSprite : SKSpriteNode

 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *jumpFx;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *DjumpFx;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *hurtFx;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *dashFx;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *defeatFx;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *powerFx;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *bounceFx;
 @property (nonatomic,strong)SKAction *rocketFx;
```

In my ActionSprite.m

```
  @implementation ActionSprite

- (id)init {
   if (self = [super init]) {


  }
  return self;
  }

- (void)preLoadSound {
_jumpFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"jump.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
_DjumpFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"dJump.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
_hurtFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"cat hurt.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
_defeatFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"defeat.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
_bounceFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"bounce.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];
_powerFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"power.mp3" waitForCompletion:NO];
_rocketFx = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"rocketFx.wav" waitForCompletion:NO];

}
```

preload sounds in the cat class

```
 @implementation Cat

 SKTextureAtlas *catAtlas;

   - (id)init {
   if (self = [super initWithImageNamed:@"idle.png"]) {
    catAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"idle.plist"];

    [self preLoadSound];

}
return self;
}
```

no more lag! :D